# IoT questions on other sites we can learn from

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Recently, there was an IoT related question about WiFi modules on EE.SE.

[Wifi-enabled IoT boards with AP mode and SSL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274690/wifi-enabled-iot-boards-with-ap-mode-and-ssl)

The question itself has been closed as primary opinion based, which it was actually. Also there was product recommendation request in it which is also off-topic on most of the SE sites.

IMO the problem with this question is that the OP ask too many things in a single question. For example the following questions can be quite useful:

> Are there any counterpoints in using any of these modules? I mean, do they "hang" like the CC3000 without a good reason? Can they be left running for months at a time?

As the OP has done a little research about the different boards. Asking which one of them is the most suitable for a long term application that requires high stability could be useful.

All in all my question is:

In what form can this question be asked on this site? What parts of it make it on or off-topic here?

Comment: Copy editing through comments: "In what from" -> "form"

Comment: @Ghanima Fixed it, thanks for the review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't think that this questions shows a lack of research its two major problems are being too broad and still somewhat opinion based.

First important thing to make it a better fit would be to focus on a single issue - *reasonably scoped*. Right now it is asking ten questions and that's not a good fit for the StackExchange system where it is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining many questions into one. Put differently asking separate questions helps the people answering to focus on aspects the feel most comfortable answering according to their specific knowledge and experience. In this particular example a comprehensive answer would require knowledge on multiple platforms. While it is clear that there are experts out there that possess that knowledge it limits the base of potential responders to just those. Multiple specific questions gives users with "limited" experience (for lack of a better word) a chance to contribute - which is something we should encourage.

With regard to *opinion based* questions the [helpcenter](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) gives us some leeway if they are *constructive* - which seems to be the case here. I think that it is possible to have "which plattform is *better* suited for a particular task" answered mainly based on experiences over opinions and *explain “why” and “how”*. We just need to be careful to not let it slip down to a flame war about platforms but I believe that community moderation can put a quick and effective stop to such things.

... and there is of course the question which parts of the actual content are on-topic here but I will leave that to another answer.